# ASP.NET - How to wrap GridView Delete in try catch or stop a row delete

Tags: asp.net, gridview, delete-row

I want to be able to wrap a gridview row delete in a try catch and display a nice error message on the screen or try to stop the delete from happening in certain circumstances.

At the moment, I am getting foreign key violations in the database.   So I either want to stop the delete from happening if there are child records or catch the foreign key exception and display a nice error message to the screen.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You mean the foreign key exception is thrown within your row delete call? Or you do not code the delete function but letting the framework to do it for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GridView Row Deleting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx)

Here is a sample code for that :

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDeleting
        (Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell cell = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
        if (cell.Text == "Beaver")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Message.Text = "You cannot delete customer Beaver.";
        }
        else
        {
            Message.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another +1 for the same beaver!

Comment: When does the row deleting fire?   Before or after the associated data source delete?   I tried the above but it doesn't seem to be be called.

Comment: @Gordyll : There is actually two different events handler to handle the row deleting and row deleted. Row deleting will be fired when row is being deleted so you have a chance to cancel the deletion process or change same during that process but row_deleted is fired after the selected row is completely deleted. You can find more information Here : http://is.gd/4ipXz  go ahead and have a look, you like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using the datasource ***Deleting*** event might be cleaner as one does not depend on the GUI elements and their possible repositioning that might break the code.